# How to run Amarok after installing?

Tags: installation, fedora, amarok

On my Fedora machine, I installed Amarok using

```
yum install amarok
```

In the Fedora start menu, and entry is created 'Amarok'. But, when I click it, a window opens and closes itself.

I am not able to use Amarok. How do I run it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run it from the command line first.  Maybe it's displaying an error and it doesn't give you enough time to see it before closing itself.

Comment: +! Running from terminal should display an error message, if something's going wrong. Could also try out diagnostic mode - `amarok -d`

Comment: on the terminal, typing `amarok` does nothing. Neither does `amarok -d` what can the problem be?
btw, how do I uninstall amarok now (to try to reinstall it?)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Fedora, but it's like this on Ubuntu, there should be an icon pasted in the "multimedia" or "sound/video" menu.

Answer (score 0):

Run via command line (at least on opensuse) amarok %U

If there missing or broken dependencies, this will usually spit them out to the command line. You might also run as root and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Simply type `amarok` from the commandline. Based from the opening and closing behavior of it when you click the entry from the menu, it's probably encountering problems during launch. Running it from the commandline should give you the error messages and clues on how to fix the problem.